# Starting a binary using start-stop-daemon prohibits using UDP

Tags: linux, ubuntu, udp, daemon

I have a binary that listens using UDP waiting for commands.  When started by the root user it works great.  But if started by start-stop-daemon at boot up I see "Bad file descriptor" errors in the UDP routine.

This is a Linux/Ubuntu ARM based board running a 3.4.0-1489-omap4 kernel.

start-stop-daemon --version
start-stop-daemon 1.16.1.2 for Debian

The start-stop-daemon command looks like this:
start-stop-daemon --start --startas $home/program --pidfile $home/program.pid --make-pidfile --background -- -argument

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Silly question, but what's the port number your UDP routine is listening on? The lower numbers, I believe it's below 1024, need root.

Comment: It struck me that at boot up the network may not be available and subsequent accesses may fail.  I will test this and post a follow up.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I was trying to connect before the network was up when I started from boot up scripts.  I added a 10 second delay inside the application and the UDP communications started working.  I'll have to revisit this when I have more time to create a proper solution.